# Prevent controller from running before HTTP request is fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, promise

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if ($rootScope.carNameMap) {
        _import.stateEvent.changeTitle(toState, toParams, event);
    } else {
        _import.getCompanies.init().then(function(res){ //<-- promise
            _import.stateEvent.changeTitle(toState, toParams, event);
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see, in my `$stateChangeStart` I check if `carNameMap` was already created, if not I run a service that sends HTTP request, and returns a promise.

But when I have a remote db, my controller runs before `http request` ends.

**How can I prevent controller from running before HTTP request is fulfilled?**

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the resolve functionallity that angularJs provides in the $routeProvider in the config blocks:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
      templateUrl: "app.html",
      controller: "AppCtrl"
      resolve: {
        foo: function ($q) {
            //your logic goes here, and then your controller will receive an "foo" parameter.
        }
      }
    }
  )
});
```

Comment: OK what if I need it to be on every view?

Comment: If every view needs to resolve the same call you could move the function to a scope that all views share, something like 'foo: myResolveFunction'

Comment: so there is no way to make it work in the `$stateChangeStart` event?

Comment: I think that states in common use the same controller, so if you use the resolve in a controller that has more than one state, it should be working for all states, but i'm not sure.